# Почему пара ботинок, чулок, погон, но: пара носков?

Tags: существительные

Какими правилами регулируется употребление двух видов окончаний для существительных м.р.в форме Р.п. - окончания ОВ и нулевого окончания?

Answer (score 1):

В родительном падеже множественного числа в каждом типе склонения можно обнаружить несколько вариантов окончаний.
В целом при образовании этой формы действует следующая закономерность:

- Если в начальной форме  слово имеет нулевое окончание, то в родительном падеже множественного числа окончание обычно ненулевое:
  дом – много домов, конь – много коней, степь – нет степей.
- Если же в начальной форме окончание ненулевое, то в родительном падеже множественного числа оно будет нулевым:
  земля – нет земель, петля – нет петель, дело – нет дел, место – нет мест, клеймо – нет клейм, яблоко – нет яблок.
  Так язык стремится избавиться от совпадения начальной формы и косвенных форм существительного.
  http://licey.net/russian/culture/2_2_3

Нулевое окончание обычно имеют:

- названия парных предметов:

  пара ботинок, пара валенок, пара сапог, пара чулок, но: пара ботфортов, пара ботов (допустимо – пара бот), нет рельсов(допустимо – нет рельс);

Существительное носок в родительном падеже множественного числа имеет два литературных варианта – нет вязаных носок и носков, хотя совсем недавно признавалось нормой только НОСКОВ. С чем связано такое исключение, не знаю, но ассоциации были для запоминания, что из этой пары (чулки-носки) пишется с нулевым окончанием, что с ненулевым, такие: что само по себе длиннее, то пишется короче, с нулевым окончанием: носков, но чулок. Теперь во многих словарях варианты равноправны. У Лопатина не знаю - не проверяла.

Comment: >Так язык стремится избавиться от совпадения начальной формы и косвенных форм существительного.  
  
Это о чем вообще? Тут скорее наоборот, наблюдается тенденция к упрощению ("укорочению") формы родительного множественного, т.е. к сипользованию парадигмы ж.р. (носок, сапог и и.д.). Это приводит к совпадению форм Им. р. и Р. мн.   
Какое уж тут "избавиться от совпадения".

Comment: В Грамматике-80 говорится о том, что сущ. м.рода в форме Р.п. мн.числа имеют основное окончание ОВ/ЕВ и вариантное нулевое окончание. Всё-таки не очень понятно, почему именно парные предметы имеют нулевое окончание. Может быть, они чаще всего встречаются в  форме мн. числа и поэтому нет необходимости в различении форм "ботинок" (ед.ч.) и "пара ботинок"?

Answer (score 1):

Правила как такового тут нет. Есть некий набор свойств, носящих скорее статистический характер.

Вот с Грамоты:

> Для большей части существительных мужского рода, в начальной форме оканчивающихся на твердый согласный (апельсин, помидор, мухомор, компьютер, носок), характерно окончание -ов в форме родительного падежа множественного числа: апельсинов, помидоров, мухоморов, компьютеров, носков и т. д. Из этого правила можно выделить обширный ряд исключений - подобных существительных, но имеющих в форме родительного падежа множественного числа нулевое окончание: один чулок - нет чулок, один осетин - пятеро осетин, один грамм - пять граммов и пять грамм и т. п. К числу таких слов относятся:
>
> Названия людей по национальности и по принадлежности к воинским соединениям, преимущественно употребляющиеся в формах множественного числа в собирательном значении: мадьяры - мадьяр, туркмены - туркмен, гардемарины - гардемаринов и гардемарин, партизаны - партизан, солдаты - солдат; сюда же относится форма р. п. мн. ч. человек.
>
> Названия парных предметов: ботинки - ботинок, глаза - глаз, манжеты - манжет, погоны - погон, чулки - чулок, эполеты - эполет, сапоги - сапог.
>
> Названия мер и единиц измерения: 220 вольт, 1000 ватт, 5 ампер, 500 гигабайт. Если же такие названия употребляются вне "измерительного" контекста (иначе говоря, форма родительного падежа не является счетной), то используется окончание -ов: жить без избыточных килограммов, не хватает гигабайтов.

http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/?rub=plural

От себя добавлю несколько мыслей из того, что вспомнилось.

*Надо сказать, что такое объединение в группу по признаку парности не всегда очевидно с исторической точки зрения и часто может быть оспорено (для тех же ворот, например, или рельс), но тем не менее такая тенденция подмечена.

Несмотря на противодействие всех словарей, существует явная тенденция употребления Р.мн. названий небольших плодов, фруктов и овощей с нулевым окончанием: апельсин, помидор, абрикос. В некоторых случаях такое употребление уже признается нормативным (баклажан).

Р.мн. особой формы с нулевым окончанием имеют большинство существительных на -онок/-ёнок: козлят, зайчат, поросят, опят (наряду с устаревающим "опенков"), маслят и т.д. Но: бочонков.*

Существительные, оканчивающиеся на шипящий или мягкий согласный обычно имеют "женский" вариант родительного множественного на "-ей": ножей, ключей, учителей, токарей, голубей, коней.

Comment: А вы сами как относитесь к апельсинам и помидорам с нулевым окончанием в Р.п.? Мне кажется, москвичи вряд ли одобрят нулевую тенденцию, тем более что так в основном выражается народ приезжий.

Comment: Я  - против. Принимаю разве только как счетную форму - но тоже с большим сомнением.